# Undefined Index Error altough correct programming

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

As many people, I got the error:
**"Notice: Undefined index: email in ...\login.php on line 8"**

Line 8 being:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Where we get the 'email' from this form: (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
 </head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="login.php">
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

Don't have an account? Create <a href="create.html">here</a>.
</body>
</html>
```

Login.php looks like this:

```
<?php
    require_once("db.php");
    require_once("functions.php");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        global $connection; 

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $safe_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $email);

        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '{$safe_email}'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $set_password = $row['password'];
            $input_password = crypt($password, $set_password);

            if($input_password == $set_password) {
                echo "winnar";
            } else {
                echo "wrong password";
            }
        } else {
            echo "we didn't recognise this email in our database";
        }
    }
?>
```

I checked spelling, closing tags, mistakes in ending code, searched some Stackoverflow questions, but nothing seemed to help. As if the e-mail was never POSTed, yet it should be.

Comment: what about input closing tags: <input />

Comment: do `var_dump($_POST);` and see what you get

Comment: var_dump($_POST) told me that it was saved under "e-mail" instead of "email". Yet I never use in my code the word "e-mail"

Comment: @mikeO. let me tag you

Comment: @mikeO. it was a problem with Google Chrome cashing certain stuff.

Comment: @Xela: whilst I too preferred XHTML, HTML5 doesn't require tags to be closed - they gave up on that standard.